# How to push a consecutive number as string into an json object?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, json, writefile

I want to push some data into a JSON file, which has just only consecutive numbers as keys and hash string as a value.

```
   var readyFiles = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('requests.json', 'utf8'));
    console.log(readyFiles)
    const num = readyFiles.length
    readyFiles.fileHashList.push({ num : _fileHash })
    console.log(readyFiles)
    var json = JSON.stringify(readyFiles)
    fs.writeFileSync('requests.json', json, 'utf8');
```

the expected output should be like that:

```
{
    "fileHashList": [
        {
            "1": "QmWpVdqGqPGo9ApLErzxBYfxD2eABKtYCQYCXQpnbYWjro"
        },
        {
            "2": "QmTYsKnWBsVQTC1ioBHX7VWeY9tZLJXXzxuVkGiBSdBDea"
        },
        {
            "3": "QmPiszxoFdCfwtLvWihaqFuBVpbU168WNVDbHUqtmuCDj3"
        },
        {
            "4": "QmdLQ8TTg7EvJ4jvvbQiNWQUniKz6yKQugsvzVTMwNLJu1"
        },
        {
            "5": "QmcziropQqSUDbNfAkYBwsLQXdEVf9N88Nqz4K1dfKeQGL"
        },
        {
            "6": "QmSiEYVCY8G7zrc5X8UamkA6TymDyAg8dM39L7qnNFt7tY"
        }
    ]
}
```

but instead, the actual behaviour is that:

```
{
    "fileHashList": [
        {
            "1": "QmWpVdqGqPGo9ApLErzxBYfxD2eABKtYCQYCXQpnbYWjro"
        },
        {
            "2": "QmTYsKnWBsVQTC1ioBHX7VWeY9tZLJXXzxuVkGiBSdBDea"
        },
        {
            "3": "QmPiszxoFdCfwtLvWihaqFuBVpbU168WNVDbHUqtmuCDj3"
        },
        {
            "4": "QmdLQ8TTg7EvJ4jvvbQiNWQUniKz6yKQugsvzVTMwNLJu1"
        },
        {
            "5": "QmcziropQqSUDbNfAkYBwsLQXdEVf9N88Nqz4K1dfKeQGL"
        },
        {
            "num": "QmSiEYVCY8G7zrc5X8UamkA6TymDyAg8dM39L7qnNFt7tY"
        }
    ]
}
```

as you can see, there is 'num' as key in the last entry.

How can I have the next number of the keys there, espacially "6" in the above case?

Comment: `{ [num]: <value> }`, brackets around the key will make it be considered as a variable and evaluated.

Answer (score 1):

```
    const readyFiles = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('requests.json', 'utf8'));
    const readyFilesKeys = Object.keys(readyFiles.fileHashList);
    const countKey = readyFilesKeys.length + 1;
    readyFiles.fileHashList.push({ [countKey]: _fileHash })
    var json = JSON.stringify(readyFiles)
    fs.writeFileSync('requests.json', json, 'utf8');
```

1. count the keys and + 1
2. use brackets [] outside the keys makes it possible, as @Taplar commented (THANKS :) )